# How to run a method after a specific time interval in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer, python-multithreading

```html
 
def sendDataToServer():
  global temperature
 
threading.Timer(5.0, sendDataToServer).start()
print("Sensing...")
readSensor()
readCPUTemperature()
temperature = round(temperature, 1)
print(temperature)
print(humidity)
print(pressure)
temp = "%.1f" % temperature
hum = "%.1f" % humidity
press = "%.1f" % pressure
urllib.urlopen("http://www.teema.club/projectweather/add_data.php?temp=" + temp + "&hum=" + hum + "&pr=" + press).read()
 
sendDataToServer()
```

This is my Python code which sends some values to a server using a url with some parameters. I need to send this data to server after every 5 seconds. I tried to use a thread but it does not work.

Can anyone tell me is it proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run some code on a regular schedule (fixed time interval) you can use `time.sleep()` like:

#### Code:

```
next_time = time.time()
while True:   
    # do some work here
    ....

    # wait for next interval
    next_time += 5
    time.sleep(max(0, next_time - time.time()))
```

#### Larger listing:

```
def sendDataToServer(temperature, humidity, pressure):
    urllib.urlopen(
        "http://www.teema.club/projectweather/add_data.php?"
        "temp=%.1f&hum=%.1f&pr=%.1f" % (
            temperature, humidity, pressure)
    ).read()


import time
next_time = time.time()
while True:
    # Read data
    temperature = humidity = pressure = 1.0

    # Send data
    sendDataToServer(temperature, humidity, pressure)

    next_time += 5
    time.sleep(max(0, next_time - time.time()))
```

Comment: this will halt my program for certain seconds. What if I want my other functions to be in a running state at that moment. Apart from multithreading is there some another way how i can achieve this?

Comment: @Ishanmahajan, There are myriad ways to do this.

Comment: can you please list out some of them.